# How to return line in C# link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to concatenate ARTICLE and reference to have a third element content concatenation between ARTICLE and reference.

This is my code:

```
var model = (
    from article in db.article
    select new {
        ARTICLE = article.Article, 
        reference=article.reference
    });
```

I've tried that but got no result:

```
var model = (
    from article in db.article
    select new {
        ARTICLE = article.Article, 
        reference = article.reference,
        concat=article.Article+"\n" +article.reference
     });
```

but it never returns a line.

Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What *exactly* do you mean by "it never returns line"? What does it return? What happens?

Comment: Where is the view that renders this model?  We need to see that.  In html, you need to use <br> for a line break.  \n or \r\n will not render as a line break in html

Comment: Consider using `Environment.NewLine` instead.

Comment: It looks like you have some kind of problem with your data or the projection of your data. Does your first example returns something?

Comment: it returns all list  no problem in data

Comment: and the second return list but no return line and i also try Environment.NewLine the same it display concat but without returns a line.

Comment: Do you mean you can't see newline in html?

Comment: Since the concat operation principally seems to work, the question is where are you displaying this value? If it is HTML, as Pankaj suggests, you probably need to insert "<br />" for an HTML line break.

Comment: exactly no return a line